# Get number of children for a Firebase node using AngularFire2?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, observable, angularfire2

I need to count the number of children nodes for multiple subtrees in Firebase to display in the view. For context, my app is counting users at different stages in a process.

My root node (stages) has two subtrees (stageOne, stageTwo). Each subtree contains a variable number of child nodes which I need to count and display in the view.

Database:

```
stages
|__stageOne
|  |__user1
|  |__user2
|
|__stageTwo
   |__user3
```

Component:

```
stageObject: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;

constructor(public af: AngularFire){
    this.stageObject = af.database.object('/stages');
}
```

View (doesn't display)

```
<h3>Stage 1 Count = {{ (stageObject | async)?.stages.stageOne.length }}</h3>
<h3>Stage 2 Count = {{ (stageObject | async)?.stages.stageTwo.length }}</h3>
```

View (how it should look):

```
Stage 1 Count = 2
Stage 2 Count = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't get count with AngularFire2 (without loading all items), but you can use REST API:

```ts
this.http.get('https://your-app-name.firebaseio.com/stages/stageOne.json?shallow=true')
  .map(response => response.json())
  .subscribe(items => Object.keys(items).length)
```

Using **`shallow=true`** will return just keys for all children for 'selected' node.

---

If you want to load all of them, you can use `list()`:

```ts
this.stageOneObject = af.database.list('/stages/stageOne');
```

or transform object to array:

```ts
this.stageOneObject = Object.keys(this.stageObject.stageOne)
                            .map(key => this.stageObject.stageOne[key]);
```

Comment: The REST API solution results to `net insufficient resources` error in chrome browser

Comment: The rest API solution may work when there is no authentication... Otherwise it may fail.